# Cucumber Report not getting generated, throwing Message "net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!"

Tags: cucumber

I have been trying to generated the cucumber report using pluggin. Mvn clean install is giving me Error Message:
Message "net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!"
Please find error message below:

```
Feb 27, 2023 4:42:12 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder generateErrorPage
INFO: Unexpected error
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:61)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:97)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.execute(CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
```

Here is my @CucumberOption

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features="src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"steps"},
        publish = true,
          plugin = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},
        monochrome = true
)
```

Here is my POM file

```
<!--Cucumber Reporting plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumber-gbpf-graphql</projectName>
                            <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```